# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token in ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I have a form which looks like this:

```
<form id="login_form" class="border shadow p-3 rounded" method="post" style="width: 450px;">
        <h1 class="text-center p-3">LOGIN</h1>

        <div id="error_box" class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="username" class="form-label">User name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username">
        </div>

        <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="password" class="form-label">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" id="password">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">LOGIN</button>
</form>
```

When I click the login button I want to check if the given username and password are in the database. If they are, I want to move to a different page. If they are not, I add an error message text to the above div with ID "error_box" and make it visible (it is initially invisible). This is how the jquery code looks like:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            const errorBox = $("#error_box");
            errorBox.hide();
            $("form").on('submit', function (event) {
                errorBox.empty();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "controller/controller.php",
                    data: {action: "checkLogin", username: "<?=$_POST['username']?>", password: "<?=$_POST['password']?>"},
                    success: function (jsonResponse) {
                        const result = $.parseJSON(jsonResponse)["result"];
                        if (result === "success") {
                            window.location.href = "home.php";
                        } else {
                            errorBox.show();
                            errorBox.append(result);
                        }
                    }
                });
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        })
</script>
```

The function `checkLogin` from `controller.php` will return a json with one field, "result". If the username/password combination is correct, it will return {"result": "success"}. If the username/password combination is incorrect, it will return {"result": <error_message>}, where <error_message> can be something like "You cannot enter an empty username". You get the idea.

The problem is that I get an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token". The browser says it is at the line where I have `type: "GET"` in the ajax call. This exception also makes the div which will have the error message to not be hidden, so I have an empty red box above the username and password fields (and it shouldn'y be there, it should only appear after the user clicks on the login button with invalid username/password). If I delete the ajax call I don't have the exception anymore and the div gets hidden. I don't know how to solve it/why I get this exception. I tried specifying the `dataType` attribute in the ajax call as `'json'`, but that still didn't work. I tried changing the ajax call to a `$.getJSON()` call and I got the same exception (I know they do the same things, but I'm getting desperate). What's wrong?

Comment: check you don't have some odd invisible characters in your code - that's 99/100 times the answer - also, check what the code looks like *in the browser* - because it will not have the `<?` stuff - it may be something odd happening there

Comment: Security of this...not good. Why are you sending passwords on the querystring (which could get logged by a webserver and browser history)? Why are you embedding passwords into the JS code, and doing it from a POST value - meaning (if that bit is working) that it must _already have been sent to the server_...why send it again? Surely it should have been authenticated the first time it was sent? The lesson? Don't roll your own authentication, use a module / plugin / framework and leave it to the experts.

Comment: Or perhaps actually you've misunderstood something and really you wanted to get those values directly from the HTML form fields, using JavaScript? Either way, send the request as POST not GET

Comment: P.S. `window.location.href = "home.php";`..if you're just going to redirect the user the moment the AJAX request completes, then there's really very little point in using AJAX to begin with. The whole point of AJAX is to avoid needing to refresh or redirect. It can be used when the next step is to do something else on the same page. (Yes, your code will do that in the cases where the login fails, but that's going to be a small minority of cases. For the vast majority where login succeeds, you could have saved yourself the trouble and just have the form submit in the normal way.)

Comment: @ADyson I see what you're saying, I also felt that ajax is a bit overkill, but how else can I call a php function inside javascript if not with an ajax call?

Comment: You don't need to call it inside JavaScript - that's my point. Just have the HTML form submit direct to the server where PHP can read the submitted values and check the validity of the login (and then either redirect the user to the home page, or echo an error message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is php syntax in your ajax form and the problem is in those lines where you get the username and password from the inputs. Try to get the values of inputs from using jquery or javascript.

And your script should be like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        const errorBox = $("#error_box");
        errorBox.hide();
        $("form").on('submit', function (event) {
            errorBox.empty();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "controller/controller.php",
                data: {action: "checkLogin", username: $('#username').val(), password: $('#password').val()},
                success: function (jsonResponse) {
                    const result = $.parseJSON(jsonResponse)["result"];
                    if (result === "success") {
                        window.location.href = "home.php";
                    } else {
                        errorBox.show();
                        errorBox.append(result);
                    }
                }
            });
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    })
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. But can you tell me why is it wrong to use the php variables with `$_POST[]`?

Comment: @abcxyz Because javascript cannot read php scripts, javascript and php are completely different languages. If the answer helped you please put the tick)))

Comment: @abcxyz it's because when this code runs, those values have not yet been sent to the server where PHP can see them. It's your AJAX code which is doing the sending! Frankly if you are stuck on something like that, I think you should not be writing something as important as a login function, sorry. There are too many ways to screw it up without knowing. As I said above, use a ready made tool made by experts, and concentrate your efforts on adding some real unique value to your application instead. This is meant as a friendly suggestion due to your apparent experience level, not as a criticism.

Comment: @ADyson I know there are a lot of holes and I made mistakes, but this will not be deployed anywhere. It's just an exercise.

Comment: @abcxyz Well it should ideally be an exercise where you get as many bits right as possible then :-)